# Windows 10 console pop up

Tags: windows, windows-10, popups

Windows 10. Every time I restart PC, open a browser, word document, picture or any thing I get this pop up for a short time.

In picture you could see it says chromedriver32.exe.

Maybe someone had this trouble and knows how to troubleshoot it?

[image: chromedriver32.exe]

Comment: My first hunch would be something pretending to be a Chrome process. Do you have an up to date virusscanner installed?

Comment: Default Windows antivirus does not find anything wrong within system, although I am not sure if this antivirus is trustworthy

Comment: ChromeDriver is the WebDriver implementation for Chrome. It’s for remote controlling the Chrome browser. Typically used with automated testing tools, I’m getting the feeling this is not the case here.

Comment: You could get a second opinion, most antivirus providers have a free online scan option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that's not MS-DOS popup. The Windows cmd has nothing to do with MS-DOS

Answer (score 1):

The executable for the
[Chrome Web Driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)
is called `chromedriver.exe` and this unique binary is supposed to work
for both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions of Chrome.
It is not called `chromedriver32.exe` and does not reside in the indicated
folder.

Search in *Control Panel > Programs and Features* any mention of
"Chrome Web Driver" or "Chrome Driver" and uninstall it using
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/),
then reboot to see if it is gone now.

If you can't find it, then your computer may be infected.
See the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: In other words, if you have chromedriver32.exe on your system, it's NOT the Chrome Web driver and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

CCleaner is a nice software to adjust the Windows startup settings. It helps you choose which programs can be started immediately and which ones should remain off while you don’t use them. It’s really useful when you need to turn off annoying popups from apps you don’t even use.
Unfortunately, most app designers seem not to understand that popups are really annoying and might even cause the user to delete the programs that send too many of them. There might be useful popups like the ones from [promolayer.io](https://promolayer.io/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%94%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96/%E3%83%90%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E7%B4%A0%E6%9D%90%E3%81%8A%E3%81%99%E3%81%99%E3%82%81%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8837%E9%81%B8/) that offer users new coupons when they want to leave the website. It helps to boost sales and doesn’t annoy users. I wish all popups were like that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).